# Connection error while using telethon through python?

Tags: python

here is the code which I am using to operate telegram through python. But on running this, I am getting an error.

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient,connection

api_id = xxxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'


client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash,
    connection=connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate,
    proxy=('mtproxy.example.com', 2002, 'secret'))


async def main():
    # Getting information about yourself
    me = await client.get_me()
    print('hello')

await main()
```

when I run this code, I get `ConnectionError: Cannot send requests while disconnected`